# Web-site for typical GUI-solutions to common usability problems?

Tags: user-interface

A discussion happened today where a grid containing data, which ultimately had data attached to it, think master-detail type grids, and a question followed, so I thought I'd ask the question here in the hopes someone has an answer or some pointers.

If you have a problem where you're wondering *how should I do this so that the user will feel at home, or know the way to use my GUI*, is there a website or something that you can go to in order to find typical ways to do stuff?

For instance, think of a grid where you can select a bunch of things and then afterwards process them.

Such a list can be done either by using checkboxes, or multiselect. Then someone says "We need to show history data for the selected rows". Would a typical solution be sub-grids inside the original grid, which you can expand for the rows you're interested in? Would it be a popup dialog that shows history data?

This question becomes very generic, I know, but does anyone know of any site that has things like this, even remotely useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Pattern Library](http://www.welie.com/patterns/) at Welie.com is incredible.  It gives you common scenarios, the theory behind it, and examples of live sites that follow the pattern.

I am not a web designer, but appreciate this site immensely.

Comment: Nice, this looks like exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this site](http://www.ecommr.com/) the other day, which is more of a reference of how others have done things, but could be useful (especially as it builds up a bit more).